# SQL Server order by syntax with Case When and a Constant

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I'm reading TSQL code someone else wrote and find a somewhat weird syntax. It's doing order by a string. I did some test and the following is the code. Anyone can help me to explain it? Thanks.

**First Query**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Products
```

*Result:*

```
ProductID   ProductName                     SupplierID  CategoryID  QuantityPerUnit      UnitPrice             UnitsInStock UnitsOnOrder ReorderLevel Discontinued
----------- ------------------------------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- --------------------- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
1           Chai                            1           1           10 boxes x 20 bags   18.00                 39           0            10           0
2           Chang                           1           1           24 - 12 oz bottles   19.00                 17           40           25           0
3           Aniseed Syrup                   1           2           12 - 550 ml bottles  10.00                 13           70           25           0
4           Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning    2           2           48 - 6 oz jars       22.00                 53           0            0            0
...

*/
```

**Second query:**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Products
WHERE   ProductID < 10
ORDER BY '3';
```

*Result:*

> Msg 408, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 A constant expression was
>   encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1.

**Third Query**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Products
WHERE   ProductID < 10
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SupplierID = 2 THEN '1'
              WHEN SupplierID = 1 THEN '2'
              ELSE '3'
         END;
```

*Result:*

```
ProductID   ProductName                              SupplierID  CategoryID  QuantityPerUnit      UnitPrice             UnitsInStock UnitsOnOrder ReorderLevel Discontinued
----------- ---------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- --------------------- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
4           Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning             2           2           48 - 6 oz jars       22.00                 53           0            0            0
5           Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix                   2           2           36 boxes             21.35                 0            0            0            1
1           Chai                                     1           1           10 boxes x 20 bags   18.00                 39           0            10           0
2           Chang                                    1           1           24 - 12 oz bottles   19.00                 17           40           25           0
3           Aniseed Syrup                            1           2           12 - 550 ml bottles  10.00                 13           70           25           0
6           Grandma's Boysenberry Spread             3           2           12 - 8 oz jars       25.00                 120          0            25           0
7           Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears          3           7           12 - 1 lb pkgs.      30.00                 15           0            10           0
8           Northwoods Cranberry Sauce               3           2           12 - 12 oz jars      40.00                 6            0            0            0
9           Mishi Kobe Niku                          4           6           18 - 500 g pkgs.     97.00                 29           0            0            1

(9 row(s) affected)
*/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Order by" has to be able to translate each row into a value, then those values can be compared. "Order by '3'" doesn't make any sense as a useful query, as it's not using the row - hence the error message of ordering by a constant expression.

"Order by (some expression returning a string)" makes perfect sense. I would personally have used numbers rather than strings, but fundamentally it's still just ordering by a value.

Would you have found it odd to see "order by ProductName"? That's ordering by a string too.

Hopefully that helps - it's not really clear which bit was causing a problem though.

Answer (score 5):

In your first SQL query, the original coder might have meant

```
ORDER BY 3
```

which means "order by the 3rd column" (which is `SupplierId`), in ascending order.

In the second query, as @Kokizzo has explained, the author has hard coded the query so that Products from `supplierId` 2 are at the top, followed by those from `supplierId` 1, and then all rows from other suppliers. The purpose isn't clear, but for example, this could be a nefarious attempt to promote a certain supplier's products above others e.g. in a web search result page.

The `CASE WHEN .. ELSE ... END` can be equated to a simple function applied to each row, which takes the `supplierId` as input and returns the precedence of that row used in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Quite likely explanation IMO. The results do happen to come back in ascending order of `SupplierID` and in SQL Server 2000 (or 2000 compatibility mode) this ordering by constant expression does not raise a syntax error either.

Comment: I think this is the most likely scenario. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

```
CASE WHEN SupplierID = 2 THEN '1'
     WHEN SupplierID = 1 THEN '2'
     ELSE '3'
     END
```

is equal to (in pseudocode):

```
if supplierId = 2 then 
  order_value = 1
else if supplierId = 1 then
  order_value = 2
else 
  order_value = 3
end
```

so the order now is according to the order_value