# Is it possible to make LINQ's OrderBy operation maintain the original order of an IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, entities

When attempting to page a search result set based on an `IQueryable` I get an error stating that I must call `OrderBy` before using `Skip`.

In most cases, this is fine as I can just order the results by Id.  However, I have an edge case where in I am calling a Function Import via my entity class.  This function import uses a `FREETEXT` search in SQL and returns a ranked result set.

I need to maintain--and be able to page through--that result set, but if I call `OrderBy` against any of the columns in my result set, I will no longer have a set of *ranked* search results.

So, as silly as it sounds, is there a way to *fool* LINQ into thinking that I have called an `OrderBy` operation that just maintains the original order?

Comment: If you are doing hardcore sql then you can handle the paging in sql using OFFSET FETCH or TOP and Row_Number

Comment: Thanks, but I need to focus on solving the problem in C#.

Comment: It translates to sql `Row_Number() OVER (Order by ?)` so it looks as though it would be impossible without an `.OrderBy(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var page = searchResultSet.OrderBy(x => 0).Skip(40).Take(20);
```

That will maintain the original order of your result set, because all records will have the same constant value of 0, hence sorting them won't change their order after comparing their equal values.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9850680/2300466)